# rails database creating double entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, fixtures

I am using fixtures to pre-populate my database with some information, so I can kill the database and remake it quickly during testing.

Now when I create a new entry in the database using my rails application it is creating two rows with the same information and timestamping one of them as if it were created with the fixture.

here are some lines from the database

```
| task_id | procedure_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      13 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      23 |            5 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       7 |            6 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       3 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       7 |            5 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      27 |            6 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      21 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      21 |            7 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      38 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      38 |            7 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      37 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       5 |            8 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      37 |            7 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       5 |            7 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      30 |            5 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|       3 |            7 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      41 |            2 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 |
|      41 |            3 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 |
|      41 |            4 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 | 2010-11-01 23:44:15 |
|      42 |            1 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      42 |            1 | 2010-11-01 23:45:11 | 2010-11-01 23:45:11 |
|      43 |            1 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 | 2010-11-01 23:40:32 |
|      43 |            1 | 2010-11-01 23:51:16 | 2010-11-01 23:51:16 |
```

As you can see the time 23:40:32 was when the fixtures updated the database.

Note the last two sets of entries where task_id is 42 and 43, it has been added for procedure_id 1 twice, once during the initial set up apparently and once when I actually did it.

These tasks are not in the fixtures, I didn't add them to the database until after the initial load.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for procedure in @task.procedures
  @procedureTask = ProceduresTask.new()
  @procedureTask.procedure_id = procedure.id
  @procedureTask.task_id = @task.id
  @procedureTask.save
end
```

should be:

```
for procedure in @task.procedures
  @procedureTask = ProceduresTask.new()
  @procedureTask.procedure_id = procedure.id
  @procedureTask.task_id = @task.id
end
```

using both .new and .save was creating two entries? I thought .new didn't save to the database, but after removing the .save it worked fine.